# Не вызываются операторы

Tags: c#, if

Имеется код:

```
Match match = regex.Match(responseFromServer);
if (match.Success)
{
    var input = responseFromServer;
    var split = input.Split(':');
    var final = split[3];
    ProcessStartInfo mcStartInfo = new Shitocode;
    Process.Start(mcStartInfo);
    this.Close();
}
else if (responseFromServer == " Bad Login")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Uncorrect login/password!");
}
else if (responseFromServer == " Old version")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Launcher is old!");
}
```

Почему не вызываются 2 последних оператора? :)

Попробовал так:

```
if (match.Success)
        {
            var input = responseFromServer;
            var split = input.Split(':');
            var final = split[3];
            ProcessStartInfo mcStartInfo = new Shitocode;
            Process.Start(mcStartInfo);
            this.Close();
        }
        else if (responseFromServer.Equals("Bad Login"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Uncorrect login/password!");
        }
        else if (responseFromServer.Equals("Old Version"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Launcher is old!");
        }
```

В ответ ничего не происходит

Comment: Какие два последние оператора?

Comment: Извините, но за var при рождении руки отрывать надо, здесь же не объекты черт пойми какой вложенности, а примитивные типы. Зачем нужно объявлять неиспользуемые переменные? Если есть желание сравнить строки по значению, то юзать equals - responseFromServer.Equals(" Bad Login"); проверьте, что ответ сервера точно такой какой ожидается.

Comment: А что будет выполнятся если match.Success = false, а responceFromServer != " Bad Login" || " Old version"

Comment: else if - вообще не вызывается. var нельзя внутри if? Если match.Succes = false будет выполняться 2 следующих, а responceFromServer != " Bad Login" || " Old version" где " Bad Login" это неправильный пароль, а " Old version" - старая версия программы. Так что вариант с ИЛИ не подойдёт

Comment: Давайте скажем немножко проще -- как вы отработаете некорректный responceFromServer, если он не бэд_логин и не олд_версион. Да, var можно внутри if, просто в данном случае это довольно "грязный" код.

Comment: Эээ. а чем не нравится var то? То что далее эти переменные не используются не говорит о том что они не будут использоваться?

Comment: >>Эээ. а чем не нравится var то? То что далее эти переменные не используются не говорит о том что они не будут использоваться?
Именно этим и не нравятся.

Comment: @Mirdin, тем что не используются? Или тем что будут использоваться?

Comment: Немножко "философии":) Зачем нужен var? Ну в тех случаях когда у нас сложный запрос в Linq или к базе данных, где возвращаемый тип может в будущем изменится вне зависимости от программы (добавится колонка в таблицу или изменится схема XML) вроде бы понятно. Когда один раз в одном скопе лезем в глубины какого-то класса, то же. Но заменять им очевидный string -- некрасиво.

З.Ы. Пишите программу так, как будто сопровождать ее злобный психопат, который знает где вы живете

Comment: @Mirdin, во первых сам майкрософт предлагает использовать вар везде где значение справа приводится к нужному типу. Т.е. впринципе стремится чтобы слева всегда был вар. Чем это удобно? Скажем, примирительно к текущему коду - если его реформировать аля:

            var input = responseFromServer;
            var final = GetFinal(input);

то в дальнейшем, при изменении типа responseFromServer, нам этот кусок кода менять не надо. Т.е. впринципе что Вы и говорите. 
И злобный психопат, думаю, занимаясь рефактором, будет больше расстроен если тут будет не вар а стринг - т.к. больше править.

Comment: @Чад и чем же он будет расстроен? Изменить один понятный тип на другой что-ли? Попадался мне код где везде var (реально везде, и по вашей логике это правильно), да он вообще не читаем. Какое счастье, что этих варов нет в джава.

Answer (score 1):

А не вызываются видимо потому что условия не выполняются? Вы в дебаге пройдитесь посмотрите...

**Р.S**

Товарищи [[@Mirdin](/users/7200/mirdin)](/users/7200/mirdin), [[@rasmisha](/users/7315/rasmisha)](/users/7315/rasmisha) если Вам действительно интересна дискуссия по поводу применения **var**, то давайте оформимся отдельным вопросом, к теме текущего оно отношения вообще не имеет.

Comment: @Чад, законочился лимит коментариев, поэтому пишу в ответе. var - это для применения "здесь/сейчас", когда не особо важно что за тип, главное данные. Но выходя за пределы нескольких строк, он способен конкретно запутать ваш код, особенно если var несколько, и вызвать ошибки. Собственно не стоит в языке со строгой типизацией использовать JSстиль.

Comment: @Mirdin, Таки в применение к стрингам вопроса - как они не "здесь и сейчас"? Но вообще этот вопрос про вар - дело привычки - мне например удобнее var нежели прямое указание типа, т.к. - больше влезает на эран, меньше загромождённости, стимулирует понимать что возвращает инициализация нежели ожидания определённой реакции и т.д.
Близки решарперские тезисы: http://habrahabr.ru/post/39231/

Comment: @Чад, конечно дело привычки, но с помощью var уж очень легко сделать из кода головоломку. Простенький пример опираясь на вышеуказанный код

var input = responseFromServer;
var final = GetFinal(input);

// ... какой то код

if (input == final)
{
// ... какой то код
} 

А если эти кусочки расположены в разных файлах (partial класс например)

Comment: Ну такое не возможно же вроде (партиал) - разная область видимости?

Comment: партиал -- один класс, разбитый на несколько файлов, откуда тут разная область видимости.

Comment: @Чад написал в той ветке, а вы уже тут. Вы реально сталкивались не со своим кодом, а с чужим где сплошной var? Или давали своим коллегам почитать свой код из сплошных var? Что действительно читаемо? Может быть у вас есть что-нибудь на гитхабе/битбакет посмотреть? Про разную область видимости удивило

Comment: Не путайте область видимости с наймспейсом...

    void test(){if(true){ var x = y; }} 

как x может переползти в другой файл с помощью партиала?
Более того как x может выползти за if ?

Comment: А как namespace связан с одним классом находящимся в разных файлах?

Comment: один файл:
partial class A
{
var a;
}

второй файл:
partial class A
{
int foo()
{
if(a)
{
return 1;
}
}
}

Comment: @Чад Вы же нам говорите, что вы везде используете var, спор по-моему ушел далеко от изначального кода из вопроса

Comment: гм... конструкция типа partial class A { var a; } не пройдёт в компиляторе...

Answer (score 0):

[@Чад](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4),

> Не путайте область видимости с
> наймспейсом...
>
> void test(){if(true){ var x = y; }}
>
> как x может переползти в другой файл с
> помощью партиала? Более того как x
> может выползти за if ?
>
> гм... конструкция типа partial class A
> { var a; } не пройдёт в компиляторе...

Никогда так, не писал, проверил, таки да не пройдет, тогда другой пример:

один файл:

```
partial class A { int foo1 () { return 1; } }
```

второй файл:

```
partial class A 
``{ 
    int foo2 () 
    { 
    var a = foo1();
    if(a==1) { return 1; }

    }
  }
```

Провели рефакторинг -- что бы узнать что теперь хранится в а (а==1 - теперь ошибка), прийдется лазить как минимум по двум файлам.

Comment: гм... а что изменится от того что будет int a = foo1()? кроме того по if(a==1) и так понятно что оно аля int... а чтобы сделать качественный рефактор всё равно надо будет лезть в foo1()

Comment: Если будет int a -- то ошибка будет именно на этой строке, var a -- ошибка будет на строке (a==1), в реальной программе может все гораздо менее очевидно, строки разнесены более чем на один экран, а быть каким нибудь классом, интерфейсом и т.д. поэтому до определенного момента все гуд, а потом шаманизм... А если таких переменных много... лучше, чтоб человек который будет сопровождать код, не знал вашего адреса, даже если он белый и пушистый флегматик.